# Saving all user input data in Django simply?

Tags: django, django-models, django-sessions

This is may be an obvious question to a Django expert, but is there a way that I can save all user inputs (clicks through content without having to explicitly save every entry in a table). If this is possible, then how do I access it later?

If I have to create models, like this I can:

```
#(within a view function)
UserInputs.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,
        selection1=request.POST.get('selection1'), 
        id=request.POST.get('id')),
        thumbs_up=request.POST.get('thumbs_up'),
        thumbs_down=request.POST.get('thumbs_down'),
        comments=request.POST.get('comments')
 )
```

Is there an easier way to get it done? Because I have lots and lots of different user click inputs and specifying every one like this will really slow down my application.

Is this data by chance saved in one of the sessions tables? Or can we create a custom sessions table to do this?

Comment: Use a `ModelForm`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

Comment: That takes a lot of structure, I'm wondering if Django saves this data automatically somewhere. Can I do this with logging? Something easy or simple. To me, just saving the click data directly to a model (have lots of no-form clicks too like to get to different pages), etc is easier.

Comment: a lot of structure? For simple use-cases, it takes four lines to define a form, and only `.save()` to save the form in the model.

Comment: Yeah, but I have hundreds of potential click options and lots are not forms, but going between pages, etc in my site.

Comment: How do you want to receive that data in the first place? The only data that your backend (Django) receives is whatever your browser sends, usually what gets submitted by your HTML form, i.e. what user inputs in the form fields. You're talking about clicks. Clicks on what? If he clicks on an input element like a checkbox, then the value of that checkbox will be submitted.

Comment: @NateP: actually if you have hundreds of potential click options, that is definitely more reason to use forms. `ModelForm`s does not mean you need to change the page when you submit the form. You will need to define some JavaScript to make AJAX queries then wihen the form is submitted.

Comment: Clicks that link to different pages. I have no checkboxes in my application and very few text based inputs. Almost everything is clicks through content, so I want to save CLICKS. Let me change above.

Comment: Are you talking about analytics? How users navigate your site?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Good luck with building your own :-) That's what other companies have been building for years to provide as add-ons on your site. Google Analytics, Hotjar, etc... If you only want to save which pages your users visited, and each page is a request you get in Django, so you could add some `Middleware` to just record all your requests (don't forget to ask your users permission to do that, we have GDPR now...). But if you need to record clicks inside a page that trigger javascript events, that's more complicated and you'll have to record this in the browser, then send to your server via an API.

Comment: The middleware solution exists: Look for the package **django-request** it will record all requests to your site, i.e. page visits and api calls.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into Django-request - it's exactly what I was looking for.